# Apache Camel Resequence Program Not Working

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to run a simple re-sequence program using Apache Camel. This program uses the Java DSL to re-sequence incoming Java messages. When I run this program the messages are written to the folder but do not appear to be in any particular order based on the header value or the alphabetical order of the single word in the message body. The files Camel creates are out of order still as if the `resequence` DSL function did nothing.

**How can I get this program to actually order the messages like the `Arrays.sort()` method would do? Also, how can I get this program to resequence and then aggregate the messages in the correct sort order to a single file?**

Here is the program... I call the main Camel route via the other class that has the `main` method.

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class SortThoseMessages extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:pointA")
                .resequence(header("grocery"))

                .to("file:target/pointB");
    }

}
```

The class below has `main` and produces the messages into the queue, pointA.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;

public class NewSequenceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        CamelContext c = new DefaultCamelContext();

        try { 

         c.addRoutes(new SortThoseMessages());



        ProducerTemplate template = c.createProducerTemplate();

        c.start();

        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:pointA", "apple", "grocery", 1);
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:pointA", "orange", "grocery", 3);
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:pointA", "bannanna", "grocery", 2);

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        c.stop();

        } catch(Exception ex) { 
            System.err.println("Exception thrown -> " + ex);
            System.err.println("Now printing stacktrace...");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the files are out of order"? Are the timestamps of the files incorrect, so it is ovbvious no sorting took place? Perhaps you could add a logger into the root before and after the resequence() to see the order of the messages.

Comment: Hi @Frank when I say they are out of order I mean that the files Camel creates are in the order of how the messages were created with the ProducerTemplate. The files end in numbers - 1 for the apple message, 3 for the orange message, and 5 for the banana message. Maybe it would be helpful to use sometime of logger as you describe. Thank-you for the help Frank. :) It is confusing...

Comment: @Frank After adding in a `log` in the Java DSL, as you suggested, I see that maybe according to the breadcrumbs in the header that the messages were sequenced or sorted alphabetically. I am going to try to test it by aggregating all the messages bodies to one file so that the sorting is more apparent. :D

Comment: @Frank This works I think. If I aggregate the messages after sequencing them I can see that the message bodies have been ordered alphabetically or according to the header value. Maybe this is already done but lost when written to a file as was done in my small program above. Aggregating the messages at the end of the route before writing to a file I think shows that the messages are re-sequenced after all. :)

Comment: Regarding the filenaming: As far as I remember the ouput files are named with the message ID the message gets when it **enters the route**. In your case in the wrong order. If you don't want to aggregate the messages you could change the filename of the output: `.to("file:target/pointB?fileName=${headers.grocery}");`

Comment: Wow, that is awesome @Frank. I am going to try your code. Thank-you for the help with this Camel program. :D

Comment: @Frank Yes this works too Frank. Thank-you again for the help. Awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages maybe re-sequenced inside the Camel route but not when written to file. To see the re-sequence call the `aggregator` Java DSL to see the message bodies in the sequence order specified. The messages in the program posted are ordered according to the number of the header. The method call on the `ProducerTemplate` object reference sets the header as the integer in the last argument to the `sendBodyAndHeader()` method call.

To see the re-sequencing take effect in a single file as the destination of the Camel route please check out the example below:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;


public class ReorganizingMessages extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:pointA")
                .resequence(header("grocery"))
                .to("log://org.apache.camel.howto?showAll=true&multiline=true")

                .aggregate().constant(true).completionTimeout(100L).
                aggregationStrategy(new StringAggregator())
                .to("file:target/pointB");
    }

}
```

The code above uses a custom aggregator Java bean that can be seen below.

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class StringAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange old, Exchange new1) {
        if (old == null) { 
            return new1;
        }

        String oldBody = old.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String newBody = new1.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        old.getIn().setBody(oldBody + " " + newBody);
        return old;

    }

}
```